# El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada nula para el parámetro 'id' de tipo no anulable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un error cuando intento usar la búsqueda. El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada nula para el parámetro 'id' de tipo no anulable System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult.Un parámetro opcional debe ser un tipo de referencia, un tipo anulable o debe declararse como un parámetro opcional.
Esto es mi controlador:

```
    public class PersonController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Buscar(int id)
    {
        var mm = DataBase.getById(id);
        return View(mm);
    }
 }
```

Mi clase DataBase:

```
public class DataBase
{
    private static List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    private static int _nextId = 1;        
    public static List<Person> getAll() {
        return people;} 
    public static Person getById(int id)
    {
        var buscar = people.Find(x => x.Id == id);
        if (buscar == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("id");
        }
        return buscar;}
```

Mi vista Buscar:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Buscar", "Person",FormMethod.Get))
  {    
 <form>
 Title: @Html.TextBox("id");
 <input type="submit" 
 name="name"value="Buscar"/>
 </form>   
   }
  <p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", 
 "Create")
  </p>
  <table class="table">
  <tr>
  <th>
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
</th>
 <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => 
  model.Name)
    </th>
 <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => 
   model.Age)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Street)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Zipcode)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Street)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Zipcode)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

El routeConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que veo es que defines dos `form` anidados y esto no es valido

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Buscar", "Person",FormMethod.Post))
{    

    Title: @Html.TextBox("id");
    <input type="submit" name="name"value="Buscar"/>

}

@using (Html.BeginForm("xx", "Person", FormMethod.Post))
  { 
      <p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
      </p>
      <table class="table">
      <tr>
      <th>
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
    </th>
     <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => 
      model.Name)
        </th>
     <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => 
       model.Age)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Street)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Zipcode)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Street)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Zipcode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
}
```

Puedes tener dos form si los necesitas pero ni anidados

```
public class PersonController : Controller {

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Buscar(int id)
    {
        var mm = DataBase.getById(id);
        return View(mm);
    }

 }
```

entonces puede definir la accion de submit como post sin problema para la buqueda

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder en la pregunta...pero ahora tengo otro error : El valor no pude ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro id.

Comment: cambiaste a POST cuando se raliza el submit del form, no? por el mensaje parece que no esta legando el valor del id, podrias usar la developer tools del browser, a la cual accedes con F12 y ver la solapa network para ver que datos esta pasando en la llamada al controller, valida si en el request envia el id

Comment: He cambiado en Post pero tengo  siguiente error: El ítem modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'MvcSimpleModelBinding.Models.Person', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento modelo de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

Comment: por el mensaje pareciera que en la view defines una lista pero desde el action envias una instancia simples, valida que tipo de dato devuelves en la variable "mm" a la view, esta deberia coincidir con la que defines en el .cshtml

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro